# Node.js ignoring .then(variable => {

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

One function calls an async function which then calls another async function. However the master function (the first, non-async one) is not waiting on the .then method and is executing code and not waiting for the async functions to come back

I've tried both await and .then but to no avail

Master function:

```
validateSession(othersRequests.loginTime, othersRequests.sessionId, othersRequests.emailAddress).then(loginValid => {
   console.log('here it equals = ' + loginValid)
      if (loginValid == "Y") {
        console.log('Yay I am running');
        db = {};
        querySpec = 'SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c WHERE c.requester = "Tom"';
        queryContainer('requests',querySpec).then(resultString => {
          if(resultString != null) {
          db = JSON.parse(resultString);
          console.log('3: ' + db);
          res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'text/plain'});
          res.end('yeah that worked a treat!');
        }
      }
      )
    } else {
        console.log('session valid value: ' + loginValid);
        console.log('User session Expird!');
        res.writeHead(403,{'content-type':'text/plain'});
        res.end('Session no longer valid');
      };
      })
```

First async function:

```
async function validateSession(loginTime,sessionId,emailAddress) {
  loginValid = "N";
  x = getCurrentDate(1).substr(0,5).replace(':','');
  loginTime = loginTime.substr(0,5).replace(':','');
  x = (x - loginTime) - 40;
  if(x > 30) {
    console.log('need a session destroy');
    loginValid = "N";
    return loginValid;
  } else {
    querySpec = 'SELECT c.emailAddress, c.sessionId FROM c WHERE c.emailAddress = "' + emailAddress + '"';
    queryContainer('users',querySpec).then(resultString => {
      if(resultString != null) {
      db = JSON.parse(resultString);
      console.log('db string: ' + db);
      if(db.sessionId == sessionId) {
        console.log('session valid')
        loginValid = "Y";
        console.log('loginValid = ' + loginValid);
        return loginValid;
      } else {
        console.log('need a session destroy1');
        loginValid = "N";
        return loginValid;
      }
    } else {
      loginValid = "N";
      return loginValid;
    }
    });
  }
}
```

It is returning "here it equals = undefined" in the console for node. loginValid is a global variable so I am surprised it is undefined.

Comment: You forgot to put `return` before `queryContainer('users',querySpec)...`. *"loginValid is a global variable so I am surprised it is undefined."* In your `.then` callback it refers to the **parameter** `loginValid`. And if `validateSession` doesn't properly return a value (which it doesn't since you are missing a `return`, then that value is `undefined`.

Comment: In addition to @FelixKling's comment, you shouldn't even be using `.then` if you have access to `async`/`await`. `const resultString = await queryContainer('users',querySpec);`

Comment: @FelixKling I just to put a    return in before    queryContainer('users',querySpec) and it still comes back undefined

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Yes that worked!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: No reason why using `return` wouldn't work where `await` would (https://jsfiddle.net/zety2js8/), but as long as it works ;)